# Drop rows if not equal to another row pandas

Tags: pandas

Here is a df :

```
col1    col2    col3
A   A   23
B   A   32
C   D   43
E   E   54
```

and the idea is to only keep rows where col1 and col2 are equal and get :

```
col1    col2    col3
A   A   23
E   E   54
```

I tried:

```
for col1,col2 in zip(df1.col1, df1.col2): 
    if col1 != col2:
        df2.drop(col1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select all rows with same values in both columns by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df1[df1.col1 == df1.col2]
#alternative
#df = df1[df1.col1.eq(df1.col2)]
print (df)
  col1 col2  col3
0    A    A    23
3    E    E    54
```